# How to launch Calendar in other application?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

I need to launch Calendar in my application & give choice to user for selecting event. If user select any event then retrive that event's information & process it.

For address book, it is possible by choose() method for launching Address book, but not found any method for launching Calendar in BlackBerryEventList or EventList class.

Is there any alternative way for that then please suggest that....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import net.rim.blackberry.api.invoke.Invoke;

And use the invokeApplication method.

Comment: But i need, on selecting particular event, close Calendar application & selected event should be accessed by myApplication & process it...

Answer (score 1):

there is a mthod activate which should be overwriiten where the invoke Application metho d should be used to invoke the native calendar at the launch of the application